# biblatex: Better preview of \cite command (before biber is run)

Tags: biblatex, citing, live-preview

When using biblate, writing a citation like this

> Also see \cite{oscars_book}.

and just executing `pdflatex` once to get an early cheap preview, without running `biber` and `pdflatex` again (editors like *Latexian* do this for their preview window) I get something like

> Also see **[oscars_book]**.

But in the final document, using numeric citation It might end up as

> Also see [1].

Is there a way to customize the way \cite command renders after the first run of `pdflatex`? For example I would like to always produce [11] (not in bold).

Comment: Just to clarify: As I see it, the boldness of the preview output makes the preview visually too much different from the actual output.

Comment: Sure but without the boldness you perhaps don't realize that some cites haven't been resolved yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I personally that the output of biblatex which shows the entry is much better then the older bibtex behaviour where you simply got "??". But if you want:

```
\makeatletter
\protected\def\abx@missing#1{%
  \mbox{\reset@font 11}\ignorespaces}
\makeatother
```